# How to avoid permission validation in SaveFileDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

When using `SaveFileDialog` and selecting to save in a folder in which the user has no permission to write to, a warning dialog appears and prevents the user from continuing.

```
var sfd = new SaveFileDialog
{
    FileName = name,
    InitialDirectory = initial,
    Filter = "Text (.txt)|*.txt",
    DefaultExt = ".txt"
};

var result = sfd.ShowDialog();
```

[image: Validation]

Is there any way to prevent this validation, while continuing using the `SaveFileDialog`, without resorting to elevating the process?

Comment: I don't think you can, that windows is provided by the OS.

Comment: Yes -- run your program as Administrator. Then you can save wherever you'd like.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question as "Needs more focus"? It's a pretty focused question already. How more focused than this it can get? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

There is no setting or property that you can use to bypass the security mechanism of the operating system.

Set the `InitialDirectory` property to a folder that you know that users have write access or endure the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog` instead. It has a `CheckWriteAccess` property you can set to `false` that allows retrieving a file name even though you may not have permissions to write to that file.

This can be useful in scenarios where you allow for elevation via a separate process that can perform the save optionally when a `UnauthorizedAccessException` occurs on a write operation. An example of that is VS Code which offers to elevate on save if permissions are hit.